# Where is "textwidget" class in wordpress stylesheet?

Tags: css, wordpress, firebug

I am looking to change min-height attribute of "textwidget" class, to adjust the height of widgets in sidebar on my site [here](http://bit.ly/HFuDQg).

However, for some reason, I cannot locate this class in main css file. I've been trying to lacate it for over 40 mins now, can someone plz help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your site with Chrome's developer tools, there don't appear to be any CSS rules applied directly to `.textwidget`. If you want to adjust them, just add your own `.textwidget {}` block.

Comment: Yeah, I am using the same tool and cant understand where the 153px height of "textwidget" coming from, for CALL NOW widget it is

Comment: I've tried adding .textwidget { height: 143px;} yet it still shows 153px in developer tool